# Running a data install script using php -f /data-install-0.1.0.php

Tags: php, database, installer

I'm trying to run this script and I keep getting this error.

```
vagrant@precise32:/var/www/app/code/local/Project/Config/data/project_config$ php -f data-install-0.1.0.php 
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: this in /var/www/app/code/local/Project/Config/data/project_config/data-install-0.1.0.php on line 11
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/app/code/local/Project/Config/data/project_config/data-install-0.1.0.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/app/code/local/Project/Config/data/project_config/data-install-0.1.0.php on line 14
vagrant@precise32:/var/www/app/code/local/Project/Config/data/project_config$
```

Here is my file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @category  Namespace
 * @package   Namespace_Module
 * @author    Anna Völkl
 * @author    Christoph Aßmann
 * @author    Fabian Schmengler
 */

/** @var Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup $installer */
$installer = $this;

// Make sure the upgrade is not performed on legacy installations with tables missing
$adminVersion = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Mage_Admin')->version;
if (version_compare($adminVersion, '1.6.1.1', '>')) {

    $connection = $installer->getConnection();

    //---------------------------------------------------
    // Add variables
    //---------------------------------------------------
    $table = $installer->getTable('admin/permission_variable');
    $variableNames = array(
      'trans_email/ident_support/name',
      'trans_email/ident_support/email',
      'web/unsecure/base_url',
      'web/secure/base_url',
      'trans_email/ident_general/name',
      'trans_email/ident_general/email',
      'trans_email/ident_sales/name',
      'trans_email/ident_sales/email',
      'trans_email/ident_custom1/name',
      'trans_email/ident_custom1/email',
      'trans_email/ident_custom2/name',
      'trans_email/ident_custom2/email',
      'general/store_information/name',
      'general/store_information/phone',
      'general/store_information/address'
    );
    foreach ($variableNames as $variableName) {
        $connection->insertIgnore($table, array(
            'variable_name' => $variableName,
            'is_allowed' => 1,
        ));
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------
    // Add blocks
    //---------------------------------------------------
    $table = $installer->getTable('admin/permission_block');
    $blockNames = array(
      'core/template',
      'catalog/product_new',
      'enterprise_catalogevent/event_lister',
      'flexslider/view',
      'ebizmarts_abandonedcart/email_order_items',
      'ebizmarts_autoresponder/email_backtostock_item',
      'ebizmarts_autoresponder/email_related_items',
      'ebizmarts_autoresponder/email_review_items',
      'ebizmarts_autoresponder/email_wishlist_items',
      'tm_quickview/popup',
      'cms/block',
      'catalog/product_list',
      'tm_mailchimp/signup_general_form',
      'plugincompany_contactforms/form_embedded_view'
    );
    foreach ($blockNames as $blockName) {
        $connection->insertIgnore($table, array(
            'block_name' => $blockName,
            'is_allowed' => 1,
        ));
    }

}
```

Why does it keep saying uncaught error class Mage not found??

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 1):

The data and schema files operate within a Magento scope, specifically the "setup" scope.  When the installer runs, it's actually initializing the Magento application within the "setup" scope to run.  This then iterates through the modules and `include()`s your setup scripts.  So they *will* have a reference to `$this` when run inside of Magento's setup, but if you just run it as a standalone file, there is no reference to `$this` because the file is not operating within the context of an object.

There are two ways you can handle what you're trying to do:

### Use Magento Upgrade System

Adjust your `core_setup` table and change the `data_version` column value for your module to the version before this one.  Then clear the cache and visit the store again and this should execute.  Assuming that it's failing because of a particular error, everything up to that error should be reversed in the database or the code commented out so it doesn't create duplicates.

### Module Custom Shell Script

Your module can have a custom shell script that extends the `AbstractShell` class from Magento.  You'll just have to include it from `shell/abstract.php`.  Then you will have access to all the `Mage` class methods and models you need to perform a task.  The downside to this means that to run this in production means you need to SSH to the server to execute it instead of just visiting the site (like using the Upgrade System above would do).

> Why does it keep saying uncaught error class Mage not found??

This happens because the `app/Mage.php` file isn't included.  If you look at the root `index.php` file (i.e. the application bootstrapper), it specifically includes `app/Mage.php` early on so the `Mage` class is available.  You should **NOT** do this within your data-upgrade file, as it will conflict with the already included class during application bootstrap/initialization.

Comment: I would like to be able to just run it through a shell script, this isn't a production environment. So you're saying write and include statement at the top like so: include 'shell/abstract.php'; < after this is inserted at the top of my file I can run it like normal? @Brett

Answer (score 1):

To run this via a shell script, I would create a folder in your module called `shell` and place this file in there.  Then the contents would be a class which will be instantiated and called at the end of the file.  Something like:

`app/code/local/My/Module/shell/data-install.php`

```
<?php
require_once(realpath('../../../../../../') . 'shell/abstract.php');

class MyShellClass extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Put your custom code here to do what you need
    }
}

$object = new MyShellClass();
$object->run();
```

If you're passing arguments to the script, you can retrieve them with `$this->getArg('my-argument')` call.

Comment: I"m including an image above in my original post. Please let me know if the file structure looks correct. Thank you. @Brett

Comment: Can you confirm that it looks in the right folder?

Comment: There is no "right" folder, since module shell scripts aren't really a "supported" piece of Magento.  But it follows the layout at the root level and makes it clear what that folder contains.  The folder should be under the `Config` folder, not at the same level.  The `shell` directory should be a part of the module, not the vendor namespace.